# No permissions to create screenshot directory when using docker image testcafe/testcafe

Tags: docker, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/testcafe/testcafe/

to run our Testcafe project and it works except that on failure the screenshot directory cannot be created due to:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/screenshots'
```

Is it possible to make this work, am I missing something?

I have tried:

```
--screenshots ./screenshots
```

and:

```
--screenshots {full path to directory}/screenshots
```

How do I give access to this docker container for writing to a directory on the host machine for future reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is creating a `screenshots` directory on your Docker host, configuring correct permissions and passing this directory to the container as a volume. You can use the following commands as a reference:

```
mkdir screenshots

chmod a=rwx screenshots

docker run -it --rm -v ./tests:/tests -v ./screenshots:/screenshots testcafe/testcafe firefox /tests --screenshots /screenshots
```

Comment: Note that this will create screenshots files and folders alright but with "user" ownership. "user" being the name of the user launching the tests inside the container. This user having an UID of 1000, if your host user does not have the same UID, you won't be able to delete the created screenshots.